# php limit active database entries

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, limit

i'm currently making a few php scripts that will let guests book a room in a hotel now there is a limit on the different kinds of rooms but how can i enforce this through php?

I currently have these room an the limits of how much they can be booked.

2 persons seperate beds limit: 11
2 persons double bed    limit: 11
suite                   limit: 1
honeymoon suite         limit: 1

within mysql I have two tables setup with a relation between those:

**bookings**
idbookings
from_date
to_date
comments

**rooms**
2pseperatebed
2pdoublebed
suite
honeymoon_suite
bookings_idbookings (the relation)

how can i enforce this limit yet let all the information stay in these tables?
I thought of an extra column that check if the booking is active or not.
or if there is a simpler option it would be greatly appreciated if that were to be pointed out.
and would there be a way so that when the T_date has been reached or excedded that the room will be set as non-active?

Comment: in booking tbl add field as "noOfbookedRooms"

Answer (score 0):

Limits are just variable or constant. To implement this in PHP, declare a [global variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and set its value to the limit

```
<?php

TWO_BED_LIMIT = 11
DOUBLE_BED_LIMIT = 11
…

?>
```

A better way would be to store these values in the database itself along with the room types. You can then read these value and store them in a variable and do your logic agains that variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do the constraints check in SQL unless you store all nights that a person stays in the hotel in a table.

So to say:

rooms:
room_id
room_type
room_cost

booking:
booking_id
customer_id

booking_nights:
booking_id
night_date
room_id

Now that is a relation where you can query everything you need. Number of nights, price, how many rooms (and which rooms) are booked a certain night, and so on. And you can prevent double bookings by setting a three-column primary key on table booking_nights.